# Pagination and htaccess troubles

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, pagination

I have some trouble with URL Rewriting, here is my .htaccess file :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^insertCom/([0-9]+)$ /routine/Commentaires/insert.php?art=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^projets\.php$ /vue/projets.php [L]
RewriteRule ^projet/([0-9]+)$ /vue/project/ListeEpisodes.php?serie=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([0-9]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L] (4)
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /vue/article.php?article=$1 [L]
```

Like I said in the title,  I have issues with pagination.

When i use

```
 mywebsite/p/2
```

it works perfectly but when I try :

```
 mywebsite/p/30
```

I am redirected to home. 
30 is not a random number, it's the last page.
But surprisingly when I want to go to

```
mywebsite/?p=30
```

It works !

Moreover, i tried to change (4) to this:

```
RewriteRule ^p-([0-9]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

And when I tried to go to

```
mywebsite/p-30
```

It worked!

How can you explain this? And how Cain use the /p/XX format?

Thanks in advance

**Plot twist: All of this happened because of web browser's cache!
Sorry for bothering you...**

Comment: Is there a directory named `p/` in your current path?

Comment: Nor p/ or page/ either

Comment: it is weird. You will need to enable rewriteLog and check the debug trace.

Comment: how can I enable it in wamp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, but I discovered the solution by simply clearing my browser's cache...
I feel so dumb...